# Azure MSI forced token refresh

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-managed-identity

I have long running jobs that use [Azure MSI tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token) to access ADLS Gen 2 storage. I am running into Azure server side [token caching](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#token-caching) issue.
This is my setup:

1. I request access token for a user managed identity from Azure, the default TTL is 8 hours.
2. That token is then given a long running job, say the job runs for 5 hours and finishes successfully.
3. Then my code requests a new token from Azure IMDS endpoint. Azure, returns me the same access token (now with effective TTL of 3 hours).
4. This token is given to a new long running job which fails after 3 hours.

I could not find any documentation on how to force a token refresh, so that when I request the second token it's expiry time is 8 hours after the second request. In fact I found a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/07/23/understanding-azure-msi-managed-service-identity-tokens-caching/) that says that force refresh is not possible.

This does not look right there should be a way to force a token refresh (get a new token with new expiry). Has anybody come across this issue and how did you solve it.

NOTE: The processes the job runs on does not have the ability to request tokens from Azure endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-http), it does not seem there is a parameter for that.

In the [token caching section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#token-caching) they also mention:

> On-the-wire calls to Azure AD result only when:
>
> cache miss occurs due to no token in the managed identities for Azure resources subsystem cache
>
> the cached token is expired

Comment: That is my understanding so far, is there a workaround for this ? i.e. can you force clear cache for managed identity ?

Comment: bumping up against this in production as well.  Not able to force a MSI token refresh and am down in prod until it expires... Is there any way to flush the MSI token for a given resource?

Answer (score 2):

I got in touch with Azure MSI team and I was told that this is a platform limitation and nothing can be done. Token can be refreshed 5 mins before expiry (7 hours 55 mins after creation time). I am told that in few months we should be able to force renew tokens after 2 - 3 hours.

Comment: Did you ever get an update on this?  Very frustrating trying to test against this!  thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no I did not, i had to monkey patch my code to handle this :(